# How to use SF Symbol as default image for Siri Shortcut?

Tags: ios, siri

I want to use SF Symbols for Siri Shortcuts instead of PNGs, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Export SF Symbol and add it to the Assets catalog, then you will be able to use it in Intents definitions.